# How to find the string contain number with suffix 'xyz' using javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Having a array of string, I want to filter(identify) the strings contain a number followed by 'xyz'.

```
Input: ['Carrot 22xyz', 'Mango', 'Banana 8xyz each', 'Kiwi']
Output:  ['Carrot 22xyz', 'Banana 8xyz each']
```

Comment: Use the available [`String`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) and [`RegExp`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#instance_methods) methods. Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). It’s strange seeing two upvotes on a question without any attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use array's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) using following regex

```
/\dxyz/
```

[image]

```js
const arr = ["Carrot 22xyz", "Mango", "Banana 8xyz each", "Kiwi"];
const result = arr.filter((s) => s.match(/\dxyz/));
console.log(result);
```

**Note:** This will also filter out the result if a `number` followed by `xyz` that is a part of a string like `"apple4xyz", "mango69xyzfast",`

If you only want to filter out that is not part of a substring then you can do as:

```
/\b\d+xyz\b/
```

[image]

```js
const arr = [
  "Carrot 22xyz",
  "Mango",
  "Banana 8xyz each",
  "Kiwi",
  "apple4xyz",
  "mango69xyzfast",
];
const result = arr.filter((s) => s.match(/\b\d+xyz\b/));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: console.log('Banana2345xyz'.match(/\dxyz/)) is identifying only one number "5xyz". How to get all digits 2345 (without xyz suffix) ?

Comment: @Udhaya Then you can use `console.log("Banana2345xyz".match(/\d+/));`

Answer (score 1):

The regex you need is `/\dxyz/`. Here is how you use it

```js
const input = ['Carrot 22xyz', 'Mango', 'Banana 8xyz each', 'Kiwi']

console.log(input.filter(mabFruit => /\dxyz/.test(mabFruit)));
```